# Predicted Survival Curves using Corrected Group Prognosis Method

Tags: r, data-visualization, survival-analysis, cox-regression

How can I plot predicted survival curves of a continuous covariate (let's say 20th and 80th percentile of the value) using the corrected group prognosis method as implemented in R by [Therneau](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/adjcurve.pdf)

For example,

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)

fit <- coxph( Surv(stop, event) ~ size + strata(rx), data = bladder )

ggadjustedcurves(fit, data=bladder, method = "conditional", strata=rx)
```

Now, this is useful because I am given two survival curves that are stratified by rx (either 0 or 1) and the conditional method is being acted upon the bladder data set. However, let's say I would like to use the marginal method but *not stratify* and instead plot my continuous covariate at 20th and 80th value but also re-balance the subpopulation. Would like any step in the right direction.

To re-state, I have a Cox model with continuous predictors. I would like to build a Cox model but not stratify on rx but have this in the model. Then, I want to pass the created Cox object into ggadjustedcurves() function with uses "subpopulation re-balancing" when given a reference data set. And then, instead of showing two survival curves stratified on a categorical variable, I want to plot two representative survival curves at the 20th and 80th percentile.

**EDIT**

My first attempt

```
fit2 <- coxph( Surv(stop, event) ~ size + rx, data = bladder ) #remove strata
fit2

# CGP

pred<- data.frame("rx" = 1, "size" = 3.2)

ggadjustedcurves(fit2, data = pred , method = "conditional", reference = bladder)
```

Is this what I think it is? Conditional re-balancing has been applied to the reference data set and then the predicted curves are generated for an individual with rx=1 and size of 3.2.

Comment: I don't understand the request to "plot two representative survival curves at the 20th and 80th percentile." Can you cite a blog, website or location in a commonly used reference that shows hot other people might be doing what you hope for?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to understand what you are truly looking for, but I think I have a rough idea. I think you want to plot the survival curve that would have been observed if every person in your sample had received a specific value for the continuous covariate. If there is no confounding, you can simply use a Cox model that includes only the continuous covariate and use the `predict()` function for a range of points in time and plot the results. If you need to adjust for confounding, you can include the confounders in the Cox model and use *g-computation* to obtain the desired probabilities. I describe this in a recent preprint: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2208.04644.pdf

This can be done in R using the `contsurvplot` package (also developed by me). First, install the package using:

```
devtools::install_github("RobinDenz1/contsurvplot")
```

Afterwards, fit your Cox model, but use `x=TRUE` in the `coxph` call:

```
library(survival)
library(contsurvplot)
library(riskRegression)
library(ggplot2)

fit2 <- coxph(Surv(stop, event) ~ size + rx, data=bladder, x=TRUE)
```

You can now call the `plot_surv_lines` function to obtain the causal survival curves for specific values of `size`, given the model. Using the `horizon` argument you can tell the function for which values you want to plot the survival curves. I choose the 20% and 80% quantile of `size` as you described:

```
plot_surv_lines(time="stop",
                status="event",
                variable="size",
                data=bladder,
                model=fit2,
                horizon=quantile(bladder$size, probs=c(0.2, 0.8)))
```

[image: example_lines]
The package contains a lot more plotting routines to visualize the causal effect of a continuous variable on a time-to-event outcome that might be more suitable for what you actually want.